# in SwiftUI NavigationView Problem with UIViewRepresentable

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xcode11

this is my `ContentView.swift` file:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            MapView()
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my `MapView.swift` file:

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let mapView = MKMapView(frame: .zero)

        return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        print("test")
    }

}
```

with these lines of codes, when I run app it prints twice `test` in console.

but when I change `ContentView` and hide `NavigationView` from it like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        // NavigationView {
            MapView()
        // }
    }
}
```

now it prints one `test` in console.

actually it mean when we use `NavigationView` with `UIViewRepresentable`, it calls twice `updateUIView` func and it seem it is wrong.

how can we handle it?

Comment: SwiftUI may at any point require views to recompute their bodies. You should not be too worried about the framework's internal workings. If you do whatever you are supposed to do inside `updateUIView()`, then all should be fine. If `updateUIView()` running twice is a problem to you, please consider explaining why is that.

Comment: I have a marker in center of map. so when user tap on it, I want to add `annotation` in map. so user can change region and tap again. but it also have a `back button`. when user tap on back, I want to delete last `annotation` from map. but in this case when `updateUIView` calls twice or more, `annotations` is delete in wrong index